# What does this "what" mean?

Tags: pronouns

> forget **what** you said...

Could this "what" mean two things?

1. relative pronoun
2. interrogative pronoun clause? as in "Do you know what I did?

Comment: "What" is the object of the verb "forget". It's acting as a pronoun here and refers to the thing that was said.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it is difficult to know the reference and the exact meaning.  Here are a couple examples:  the "what" could mean "whatever" or it could mean "everything."

> forget whatever you said...

This is similar to the word "thing." We use "thing" when we don't want to say the whole phrase again.  "Whatever" is just a generic term, so we don't have to repeat words.

OR

> forget everything you said

This has a more serious tone.  Usually, it means, "pretend you never said those words because you could get into trouble. "

Comment: @8906335678 No. Bare 'forget' at the beginning of a sentence is an imperative, a command to your hearer to forget something. What you have in mind requires a subject: "**I** forget what you said."

Comment: @8906335678 No. There is no "question", no interrogative context, in that statement: it presupposes that both you and I know what I said.

Comment: To the original poster: please don't delete your comments when someone replies.  People reading this later will only see half a conversation and they won't be able to understand it properly.

Answer (score 0):

"Forget what you said" means "Forget that which you said earlier." No more and no less.